# Iterator for void pointer ranges

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

In the old days when C was the predominant language under the hood and STL/templates were Alex Stepanov's dream, in order for programmers to achieve generality for functions and data-containers, the `void*` was used as input argument or underlying container type respectively. A typical example is [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) which is located in `<cstdlib>`.

Nowadays, when dealing with legacy code-bases or code written by dinosaurs, it's highly probable that you might stumble on such kind of data structures that most probably keep their elements in `void**` buffers. The primary goal of-course would be to gradually move the code base towards use of modern STL containers and algorithms until these old data-structures become obsolete.

However, there are also the dinosaurs. Often, very large dinosaurs like a tyrannosaur that happens to be your manager. In order to convince them of the C++/STL superiority with out questioning the "usability" of the legacy data-structures that are being functioning all these years without a problem and most probable the author is one of them, I decided to engage the issue politically.

What I thought is to craft a template iterator that could deal with such `void**` buffers and would act as a bridge with the STL algorithms (e.g., `std::sort`, `std::copy` etc.).

Down below lies in a very early stage such an iterator:

```
template<typename T>
class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T> {
  using T_ptr = std::remove_pointer_t<T>*;
  void  **pos;
public:  
  Iterator(void **pos_) : pos(pos_) {  }
  bool operator==(Iterator const &other) const { return pos == other.pos; }
  bool operator!=(Iterator const &other) const { return pos != other.pos; }
  bool operator<( Iterator const &other) const { return pos <  other.pos; }
  bool operator>( Iterator const &other) const { return pos >  other.pos; }
  bool operator<=(Iterator const &other) const { return pos <= other.pos; }
  bool operator>=(Iterator const &other) const { return pos >= other.pos; }
  Iterator& operator++() { 
    ++pos;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator++(int) {
    Iterator out(*this);
    ++pos;
    return out;
  }
  Iterator& operator--() { 
    --pos;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator operator--(int) {
    Iterator out(*this);
    --pos;
    return out;
  }
  Iterator& operator+=(int const n) {
    pos += n;
    return *this;
  }
  Iterator& operator-=(int const n) {
    pos -= n;
    return *this;
  }
  T& operator[](int const n) { *static_cast<T_ptr>(*(pos + n)); }
  T& operator*() { return *static_cast<T_ptr>(*pos); }
  T_ptr operator->() { return static_cast<T_ptr>(*pos); }
  friend Iterator operator+(Iterator const &lhs, int const n) {
    Iterator out(lhs);
    out.pos += n;
    return out;
  }
  friend Iterator operator-(Iterator const &lhs, int const n) {
    Iterator out(lhs);
    out.pos -= n;
    return out;  
  }
  friend Iterator operator+(int const n, Iterator const &rhs) {
    Iterator out(rhs);
    out.pos += n;
    return out;
  }
  friend Iterator& operator-(int const n, Iterator const &rhs) {
    Iterator out(rhs);
    out.pos -= n;
    return out;  
  }
  friend int operator-(Iterator const &A, Iterator const &B) { return B.pos - A.pos; }
};
```

My ambition is to use this iterator in the following manner. Supposedly, I had the following `class` (e.g., `Foo`):

> ```
> struct Foo {
>   int val = 0;
>
>   explicit Foo(int val_) : val(val_) {}
>            Foo()           = default;
>            Foo(Foo const&) = default;
>            Foo(Foo &&)     = default;
>
>   Foo& operator=(Foo const&) = default;
>   Foo& operator=(Foo &&)     = default;
>
>   bool operator< (Foo const& rhs) const { return val <  rhs.val; }
>   bool operator==(Foo const& rhs) const { return val == rhs.val; }
> };
> ```

And the following buffer of `void*`:

> ```
> Foo f1(1), f2(2), f3(3), f4(4);
> void* v[] = {&f4, &f2, &f1, &f3};
> ```

And then use for example `std::sort` to sort `v` with respect the `Foo` objects that indirectionally contains:

```
std::sort(Iterator<Foo>(v), Iterator<Foo>(v + sizeof(v) / sizeof(void*)));
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29540208371c7f74)

I've been careful to inherit my iterator from the `std::iterator<`[`std::bidirectional_iterator_tag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)`, T>` and not `std::iterator<`[`std::random_access_iterator_tag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)`, T>` in order to avoid treating the `void**` buffer as contiguous `buffer` of `T`s with what ever implications that might have.

Is this iterator scheme safe? Or are there any quirks or oddities that I must be aware of?

Comment: As you tagged C++17: inheriting from `std::iterator` seems to become [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated) there.

Comment: Not a big fan of using `friend` functions here (because of auto conversions that can be done by the compiler). **But** I can't think of a situation where it would fail (so only a comment rather than a review). The rest seems fine.

Comment: You're providing operator[]() so it's random access iterator already.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(v) / sizeof(void*)` can be replaced by `std::size(v)`

Comment: [Cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40117197/1014587)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Foo f1(1), f2(2), f3(3), f4(4);
> void* v[] = {&f4, &f2, &f1, &f3};
> ```
>
> And then use for example `std::sort` to sort `v` with respect the `Foo` objects that indirectionally contains:
>
> ```
> std::sort(Iterator<Foo>(v), Iterator<Foo>(v + sizeof(v) / sizeof(void*)));
> ```

This is already a disaster waiting to happen. `v` is an array of pointers, and you should only treat it as such. Try to imagine what happens one of the pointers in `v` is actually the `nullptr`?

That's perfectly legit with the original array, and also when using the old C functions such as `qsort` to sort the array itself (given that the predicate is `nullptr` aware).

As a matter of fact, using `std::sort` on the referenced values as you just did isn't even semantically the same as applying original `qsort` straight to the array. You are copying around values while the array remains unchanged, whereby `qsort` would have resorted the array while keeping the values constant.

---

> I've been careful to inherit my iterator from the
>   `std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T>` and not
>   `std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>` in order to avoid
>   treating the `void**` buffer as contiguous buffer of `T`s with what
>   ever implications that might have.

Except that is ***is*** a contiguous buffer of `T*`s. Just mind again the difference between `T` and `T*`.

Given the possibility of `nullptr`, it can't even be an iterator for `T` in any form. See the [***is dereferenceable***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) requirement.

---

Yes, not being able to bridge to `stl` sucks. But to be honest, the problem started when someone decided to write this:

```
Foo f1(1), f2(2), f3(3), f4(4);
void* v[] = {&f4, &f2, &f1, &f3};
```

instead of this:

```
Foo v[] = {Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)};
```

Which are both valid since C99.

Which could then have been a refactored to:

```
std::array<Foo, 4> v = {Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3), Foo(4)};
```

With `v.data()` giving you access to the raw array, if you actually still needed it.

Comment: Nice solution using proper ownership semantics. +1

Comment: Well spotted,  but what if I can make sure (some how, if I tell you how then I will have to kill you :P) that my buffer won't contain `nullptr`s. Do you see any other danger apart from that?

Comment: @101010 Well, next up you are going to tell me you have polymorphism in that array, and you need a list of pointers for that reason. And then I will have to tell you, that the value-semantics will horribly break with that, as they essentially enforce a static cast on the very first call-by-value, disregarding the additional memory requirements of the inheriting type, worst case leaving you with an access violation / memory corruption as a virtual method (which still resolves correctly!) attempts to access attributes not present in the base class. There goes not only the foot but the whole leg.

Comment: @101010 Nevermind, it's not going to be that bad. It's "only" going to resolve the static cast, forcefully using the copy / move constructor of the corresponding base class. It's still going to result in unexpected behavior when using any `stl` algorithm internally calling to `std::move` or `std::swap`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this iterator scheme safe? Or are there any quirks or oddities that I must be aware of?

I cannot provide an answer for this, as I'm not sure myself, but instead I leave a comment on two regarding your code:

#### Don't break encapsulation

```
friend Iterator operator+(Iterator const &lhs, int const n) {
  Iterator out(lhs);
  out.pos += n;
  return out;
}
```

This is completely unnecessary. You already implemented `Iterator::operator+=`, so just use it:

```
template<typename T>
Iterator<T> operator+(Iterator<T> const & lhs, int const n) {
  Iterator<T> out(lhs);
  out += n;
  return out;
}
```

This is just a free function. No need to `friend` anything.

#### Is this really what you want?

```
friend Iterator& operator-(int const n, Iterator const &rhs) {
  Iterator out(rhs);
  out.pos -= n;
  return out;  
}
```

This looks strange to me. First of all the `Iterator &` (a typo? This shouldn't even compile.). But especially since your `friend Iterator operator-(Iterator const &lhs, int const n)` has the same content. So ...

```
(iterator - 5) == (5 - iterator)
```

...?

#### DRY

All these `operator+`, `operator-` etc can be implemented using the corresponding "self-assign" operator. This *could* be automated with a macro. Just as an example:

```
#define OP_FROM_SELF_ASSIGN_OP(op, lhstype, rhstype)         \
  template<typename T>                                       \
  Iterator<T> operator op (Iterator<T> const & lhs,          \
                           int const rhs)                    \
  {                                                          \
      Iterator<T> copy = Iterator<T>(lhs);                   \
      copy op ## = rhs;                                      \
      return copy;                                           \
  }
```

But *if* you're using such a macro, better keep it "behind closed doors", e.g. only in the implementation file. Since these operators are probably the only ones in this specific code base it's very debatable whether it's worth the effort, though.

Comment: Nice, very constructive comments.

Comment: The macro for assignment operators. Never do that. Ever. Especially since the code is so short and can be simplified even further by using value parameters so that the copy is done automatically.

Comment: See its shorter to write it out in full rather than use the macro: https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/7b61e217386ad91a0a5c79815ace196c

Comment: @LokiAstari Ah, using a value parameter instead of a const reference is **clever**. Regarding the macro in itself: I know that preprocessor macros have a bad reputation, but they can be really useful, e.g. with the macro you're able to change the implementation of all those operators at a single place. But as I said: In this specific case it's "very debatable" whether a macro provides reasonable gain.

Comment: Again you can achieve the same effect (with the functions) by adding a layer of indirection. But for such a short function I don't see the point. The `clever` part about passing by value was stolen from the standard copy and swap idiom.